# Laravel 4 Dynamic Properties Not Working Under Certain Condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a question about dynamic properties in Laravel 4.

First, look at this `view.blade.php` file

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

League: {{$league->name}}

Teams:

@foreach($league->teams as $t)

{{$t->name}}

@endforeach

@stop
```

This is a normal case of dynamic property usage I assume.

In my machine, the file return an error: the foreach is supplied with invalid argument `$league->teams` is simply `int(0)`.

But when I use `$league->teams()->get()` it's working as intended.

Also when I use `$league->tEams` it's working too, please note the capital E.

I have added a github repo at `https://github.com/joturako/d2tm`, anyone is kind enough to explore this problem can do so.

I believe this either is a bug with laravel itself, or a combination of laravel,windows 8 and xampp i'm using; or it is just my incomplete knowlegde about everything.

Anyway, thanks for reading my question and hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: "Also when I use $league->tEams it's working too, please note the capital E." ok...explain?

Comment: when i change the letter e to capital, it working.. as long as it's not ```teams``` but ```tEams``` or ```teAms```, the error only appear when i use ```teams```.

Answer (score 0):

You have the two models belonging to each other, the relationship in Team should be

```
public function leagues() {
    return $this->hasMany('League');
}
```

Then *$league->teams* should retrieve the teams list.

Comment: but i use many-to-many relationship, and laravel document didn't say it's like this. was i wrong?

Comment: As the referenced github repo hasn't any migration file It was hard to know, then they are ok but you would need a third table with each table id. If you already have it the error is very strange.

Comment: hmm, i didn't use migration file (i am still learning), but i included a ```.sql``` file in the root. i have the leagues,teams,league_team tables, all follow the laravel naming convention :) strange that the $team->leagues works well.

Answer (score 0):

ok it's not anyone fault, it's my fault. i have a field named `teams`
in the `Leagues` table. That explain why...

I feel dumb now, hope somebody can delete this question for me.